# Piece of html/css that looks ok in firefox but not in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, wordpress, css

I have looked at this now for some while but somehow I am missing something. I have a site that looks ok in firefox and chrome but in IE the first div gets "split" to the right. It seems as if IE takes the first block element inside the div and places that in the next column. the page with the error: http://populair.eu : in IE you see it jumps to the right. I hope someone can answer this. I hope not its something simple...

the html that gets split is:

```
<div class="blockcontent">
a <a href="">b</a>
</div>
```

so a goes to the left and b to the right?

**update:** I deleted the complete contents of the style.css (so NO styling left...) and it STILL splits it *argh* then I removed even the divs in the code above ... and it STILL splits it... ok... time to go to sleep i think.

**update 2** i made a notepad file with only:

```
<HTML><BODY><DIV id=wrapper><A name=top><DIV id=content>
argh <A href="">b</A> </DIV></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

The first element in the wrapper (the a name) determines the width. If I remove that element they are shown ok. So it must be the size of the wrapper. The problem is... I have given the wrapper a width of width:750px and the column a width of 200px.

**update 3** solved

I get it the a name=top should not be between 2 divs... at least... for IE.
SOLVED

Comment: I would recommend a static screenshot in the form of a .png for IE support.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using "float: left;" to make sure your elements are nested justified to the left.  Make sure your parent wraps are sized correctly and always use "margin: 0 auto;" if there are no margin particulars.

Cheers